# include revision number from mercurial into python file template pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, version-control, mercurial, pycharm

I have a python file template defined as follows in pycharm 2016.3

```
__author__ = ${USER}
__date__ = ${DATE}
__copyright__ = ""
__credits__ = [""]
__license__ = ""
__revision__ = ""
__maintainer__ = ${USER}
__status__ = "Development"
```

for the revision number I want to use the output of the command "hg id -n" which gives me the current revision number pulled from mercurial.

what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spawn a child process and call hg in order to collect the output. I use something like [this](https://kallithea.openttdcoop.org/nml/files/45b1e0507a8d6eb50b3750bd4556e4d5a32f6188/nml/version_info.py). A bit shortened, in essence (I hope I didn't introduce errors by the shortening to the basics, it's py3, though):

```
def get_child_output(cmd):
    """
    Run a child process, and collect the generated output.

    @param cmd: Command to execute.
    @type  cmd: C{list} of C{str}

    @return: Generated output of the command, split on whitespace.
    @rtype:  C{list} of C{str}
    """
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines = True).split()


def get_hg_version():
    path =     os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    version = ''
    version_list = get_child_output(['hg', '-R', path, 'id', '-n', '-i'])

    hash = version_list[0].rstrip('+')

    # Get the date of the commit of the current NML version in days since January 1st 2000
    ctimes = get_child_output(["hg", "-R", path, "parent", "--template='{date|hgdate} {date|shortdate}\n'"])
    ctime = (int((ctimes[0].split("'"))[1]) - 946684800) // (60 * 60 * 24)
    cversion = str(ctime)

    # Combine the version string
    version = "v{}:{} from {}".format(cversion, hash, ctimes[2].split("'", 1)[0])
    return version

# Save the revision in the proper variable
__revision__ = get_hg_version()
```

Lastly: Consider to NOT use (only) the output of `hg id -n` as your version number: it is a value which is local to that specific instance of the repo only and may and will vary wildely between different clones of the same repo. Use the hash and/or the commit time as version (as well).

Comment: Thanks!! Can you comment on how to embed the __revision__ value obtained from get_hg_version() within source files? So, when I want to release project files for deployment I want all source files within project to have the __revision__ value embedded in them. How is this normally achieved?

Comment: In the build and bundling process I generate a __version__.py file which contains the version - and which can be used / queried inside the programme in the absence of the repository.

Comment: any good references or material to see a workflow for the build and bundling process?

Comment: In python you can tell setup.py along with an approriate manifest to create all this for you. I worked my way from https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html and https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html till it bundled what I needed.